# How to use else in Shell Scripting?

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting, i have some line of theme in a program i just don't understand quit these four lines:

```
current=$(wget -q -O - http://checkip.dyndns.org|sed s/[^0-9.]//g)
[ "$current" != "$registered" ] && {
wget -q -O /dev/null $UPDATEURL echo "DNS updated on:"; date 
}
```

My question about these lines are:

1- "-O" and "-q" option

a-on line one, what is the meaning of -O if it don't specified any out put file.

b-By using "-O /dev/null" on line three, is it expect to save out put on /dev/null, why? it is disabled output by using "-q" bytheway.i don't understand it's point.

2-On three last line ,is it compare two variable in "[]" and then if it is successful it start "{ }",how can i put "else" in it?

Comment: `-q`---> turn off wget output on the terminal,`-O`---> for saving output to file! Your second path is /dev/null---output written here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.

a) According to man page of wget, `-O -` will output downloaded file to the terminal. Here, after using `-O -`, you are piping that output to `sed` command.

b) `-q` disables wget output to terminal like status and all, but -O outputs the downloaded data itself. by doing `-O /dev/null` you are telling that I don't want this downloaded data to be stored anywhere nor to display on terminal. What this command is doing it to update some value on server, probably. It doesn't care about the output the server gives.

2.
If you are using `bash` as you shell, which is pretty common. You can write if-then-else in following format.

```
if [ "$current" != "$registered" ]
then
    wget -q -O /dev/null $UPDATEURL echo "DNS updated on:"; date
else
    echo "Something else"
fi
```

The syntax you are using is not an if-then-else syntax. It is just a commonly used technique that works as if-then, or ifnot-then.

Comment: You can do `cmd && then-part || else-part` provided `then-part` always returns zero (success).

Comment: Yeah. But, that is a not-so-reliable assumption. I would never assume so.

Comment: It's easy to be sure. `[ "$foo" == "$bar" ] && { make love; true; } || make war`

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks a lot for that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're new to shell scripting, let me first explain the 'man' command. 'man' stands for Manual. So 'man wget' will give you the manual page of wget.

The manual says:

```
-O -    will redirect all output to stdout, (so sed can have a go at removing 
        anything that is not your IP)

-q      will 'quiet' all other output
```

For the if then else part you will have to rewrite the code if you want anything in the else part.
The exact format of if-then-else strongly depends on your shell e.g. bash != ksh != zsh != csh != tcsh.

However, I don't think you want that in this case. Your program probably updates your registered IP address when it is different from the one it currently detects. But if it is the same, you don't need to update anything.

The wget with output to /dev/null will just call the update url, so the server will probably to something.