# How can we define some kind of interval in init.d daemon?

Tags: bash, shell

Consider these code in bash script which i asked it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585228/how-to-use-else-in-shell-scripting) question:

```
current=$(wget -q -O - http://checkip.dyndns.org|sed s/[^0-9.]//g)
[ "$current" != "$registered" ] && {
wget -q -O /dev/null $UPDATEURL echo "DNS updated on:"; date 
}
```

it should run at init.d as a daemon,so it should be run in some kind of interval,how can i put this block in the interval without using crontab.

Comment: @AvinashRaj the code works fine.i need to put it in interval.

Comment: @JohnZwinck because i started this program to be a service or daemon i tried hard and read a lot about writing a service,it is for educational use.if it was for work,i would use crone definitely,because it is fast and easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while :
do
   current=$(...)
   [ "$current...
   sleep 60
done
```

Or, if you want to background it

```
( while
  ...
  ...
  done ) &
```